# Setup the feature gate RuntimeClass in kube-apiserver

Tags: configuration, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I want to setup the feature gates argument in the apiserver pod. How I can do it? I have triedit it by using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718465/kubeadm-kubectl-kube-apiserver-turn-on-feature-gate/):

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: MasterConfiguration
apiServerExtraArgs:
  feature-gates: "RuntimeClass=true"
```

But it is not working:

```
kubectl apply -f update_api_server.yaml 
error: unable to recognize "update_api_server.yaml": no matches for kind "MasterConfiguration" in version "kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

I'm using k8s v1.13.0.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It can be done directly in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`. Adding this line to the command: `- --feature-gates=RuntimeClass=true`

Comment: Please provide where in the file one should append these feature-gates

Comment: i confirm that at least one correct solution is to add - --feature-gates=RuntimeClass=true at /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml